# angularjs $http not working in my code please check

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i have following code i want call $http but its not working its show error, when i remove $http.get content my page working fine , how to inject  $http content for retrieve server side code

```
      (function ()
        {
            'use strict';

            angular
                .module('app.cnt')
                .controller('cntController', cntController);

            /** @ngInject */
            function cntController(Contacts, cntsService, $mdSidenav,$http, User, $location,$timeout, $document, $mdMedia)
            {

                var vm = this;
                vm.brandid = $cookies.get('brandid');
                vm.$http.get("http://localhost:3010/api/cnts/mobileuser/cntlist/"+ vm.brandid).then(res => {
                    vm.contacts = res.data;
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log('asas');


                  }); 
        }
})();
```

> Message:
>       Error in parsing: "main\cnt\cnt.controller.js", Line 20: Unexpected token =>

Comment: You can directly try using $http instead of vm.$http

Comment: not working :(.

Comment: Does your browser not support ES6 arrow functions?

Comment: now working thanks.

Comment: You can share the fix here.

Answer (score 1):

**Add $inject =[ ] as a array and passing dependent services.**

Like that :

```
cntController.$inject = ['Contacts',
'cntsService','$mdSidenav','$http', 'User', '$location','$timeout','$document', '$mdMedia'] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using return because here's how i did mine

```
function cntController(Contacts, cntsService, $mdSidenav, $http, User, $location, $timeout, $document, $mdMedia) {
var vm = this;
vm.brandid = $cookies.get('brandid');

function getContacts(){
    return $http.get("http://localhost:3010/api/cnts/mobileuser/cntlist/" + vm.brandid).then(res => {
            vm.contacts = res.data;
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('asas');
        });
}}
```

and i suggest you create a service to call for your Http request

Answer (score -1):

It's a syntax error. Wrap the function args with parenthesis.

```
(res) => {...}
(err) => {...}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Parentheses are not required for single argument arrow functions.